# How to use calculated column with before_save in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, before-save

Let assume I have an Order model with `length:decimal`, `height:decimal` and `depth:decimal` column.
I have a model method that calculated the volume:

```
def volume
  length * height * depth
end
```

I have another method that calculated the special_volume:

```
def special_volume
  volume * 2.43
end
```

Let assume that I need now to save this calculated field in database, so I create volume:decimal and `special_volume:decimal` column.

I refactor my code to use before_save like this:

```
before_save do
  self.volume = set_volume
  self.special_volume = set_special_volume
end

private
  def set_volume
    length * height * depth
  end

  def set_special_volume
    volume * 2.43
  end
```

The issue is that in set_special_volume method, the volume or the self.volume is nil, because it's still not saved.

How do hundle that usecase in Rails?
Do I need before_save?

Comment: You could use `set_volume` in `set_special_volume`.

Comment: BTW, the names are misleading. `set_volume` doesn't set anything. I name this type of methods `compute_volume`

Comment: Thanks. Using `set_volume` in `set_special_volume` will call the method twice?

Comment: I confirm that the method is called twice. Is there a way to call it one time only?

Comment: Maybe. Is it a problem if it's called twice?